# Matlab write 1-bit bmp

Tags: image, matlab

How can I write a 1-bit bmp image in Matlab using imwrite or any other function. the default of imwrite for bmp is 8-bit.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html) documentation:

> If the input array is of class
>   `logical`, `imwrite` assumes the data is a
>   binary image and writes it to the file
>   with a bit depth of 1, if the format
>   allows it. BMP, PNG, or TIFF formats
>   accept binary images as input arrays.

Therefore, if you convert your image data to a [logical](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/logical.html) matrix before giving it to [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html), you should be able to create a 1-bit BMP image:

```
imwrite(logical(imageData),'image.bmp');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the image to logical (i.e. 1-bit) before the call to imwrite.

```
%# assuming the image is stored in a variable 'img'
imwrite(logical(img),'test.bmp','bmp')
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is true. However, I can not mark two answers as my accepted answer. Thanks a lot.